# URL encoding PHP

Tags: php, url, encoding

I tested [urlencode()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.urlencode.php) and [rawurlencode()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.rawurlencode.php) out and they produce different result, like in Firefox and some online encoders...

Example;

Firefox & encoders

```
ä = %C3%A4
ß = %C3%9F
```

PHP rawurlencode() and urlencode():

```
ß = %DF

ä = %E4
```

What can I do, except hard coding and replacing?

Comment: You need to understand *why* you are seeing this, otherwise "fixing" the problem is only going to result in problems later. See http://stackoverflow.com/q/1549213/50079.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

They produce different outputs because you provided different inputs, i.e., different character encodings: Firefox uses [UTF-8](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8) and your PHP script uses [Windows-1252](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows-1252). Although in both character sets the characters are at the same position (`ß`=0xDF, `ä`=0xE4), i.e., the have the same code point, they encode that code point differently:

```
 CP   | UTF-8  | Windows-1252
------+--------+--------------
 0xDF | 0xC39F |         0xDF
 0xE4 | 0xC3A4 |         0xE4
```

Use the same character encoding (preferably UTF-8) and you’ll get the same result.

Comment: Thanks gumbo it worked.

$str = "hehe näturlich  ß";
$out = iconv('ISO-8859-2', 'UTF-8', $str);
echo rawurlencode($out);

produced result i want...
thank you

Answer (score 0):

Maybe Base64 encode, and use in post, to not make visitors afraid of these URLs.