# UrlEncoding issue for string with ß character

Tags: c#, encoding, urlencode

I have a parameter which I must pass as part of a url.  The parameter contains this character: ß

When I encode this string, I am expecting this: %DF
but instead i'm getting: %c3%9f

Here is a line of C# which I have been using to test

```
  string test = HttpUtility.UrlEncode("ß");
```

Comment: See [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5921090/url-encoding-php).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is because the default implementation of UrlEncode is based on the UTF8 character encoding.  Actually this is entirely within your control.

For example, the following code:

```
string sample = new string((char)0x0DF, 1);
string test = HttpUtility.UrlEncode(sample);
Console.WriteLine("UTF8 Ecoded: {0}", test);
test = HttpUtility.UrlEncode(sample, Encoding.GetEncoding(1252));
Console.WriteLine("1252 Ecoded: {0}", test);
```

Outputs the following:

```
UTF8 Ecoded: %c3%9f
1252 Ecoded: %df
```

Of course the danger with using another encoding on a URI is that some characters can not be represented at all...

for example, this code:

```
string sample = new string((char) 312, 1);
Encoding encoding = Encoding.GetEncoding(1252);
string test = HttpUtility.UrlEncode(sample);
Console.WriteLine("UTF8 Ecoded: {0}, round-trip = {1}", test, sample == HttpUtility.UrlDecode(test));
test = HttpUtility.UrlEncode(sample, encoding);
Console.WriteLine("1252 Ecoded: {0}, round-trip = {1}", test, sample == HttpUtility.UrlDecode(test, encoding));
Console.ReadLine();
```

Will output the following:

```
UTF8 Ecoded: %c4%b8, round-trip = True
1252 Ecoded: %3f, round-trip = False
```

You can see in the later example the encoding is "%3f" which, when unencoded is equal to a question mark "?", not the input character of 312 (0x138).

In a nutshell there is nothing wrong with encoding "ß" as "%c3%9f", to the contrary, it is the correct representation.  Yet if you must have the encoding "%DF for the remote server to correctly decode it, then use the 1252 codepage as shown.

Comment: Thanks you save my day. I had the same issue, in fact the remote webservice is using WINDOWS-1252 encoding as entry.

Answer (score 4):

The `ß` character is encoded as `%c3%9f` when using the UTF-8 encoding. This is what you *should* be using, if possible.

If your target webserver uses some other encoding, you need to know exactly what encoding that is. Since you want to encode that character into `%df` that could be [Windows-1252](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows-1252) or [Windows-1250](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows-1250) (or possibly others).

If you're sure this is what you want to do, you can use (assuming Windows-1252):

```
HttpUtility.UrlEncode("ß", Encoding.GetEncoding(1252))
```

Comment: Thanks, Upvoted! I gave the answer to csharptest but you both answered my question.