# C# Method to URL encode data to '%xx'

Tags: c#, url, encoding

I am in a situation where i have to replace some Windows-1252 special characters. More characters may be added later - so i want a general method instead of this hardcoding.

```
private string URLEncode(string s)
        {
            s = s.Replace("ø", "%f8");
            s = s.Replace("Ø", "%f8");
            s = s.Replace("æ", "%e6");
            s = s.Replace("Æ", "%e6");
            s = s.Replace("å", "%e5");
            s = s.Replace("Å", "%e5");
            return s;
        }
```

Is this possible? I don't know what this '%f8' format is, but it works.

Comment: Stuff like this I always make table-driven. You can put all the OriginalChars in one field and the ReplacementChars in another, and then just loop through your table.  This way, if you need to add other pairs later, you don't have to touch the code.

Comment: That is plan B. However, there must be some method to convert a UTF-8 character into this '%xx' format?

Comment: You can convert to string using following then use winStr.SubString(0,1) to get indivual characters : byte[] input = { 0xf8, 0xe6, 0xe5 };
             string winStr = Encoding.GetEncoding(1256).GetString(input);
             byte[] output = Encoding.GetEncoding(1256).GetBytes(winStr);

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay, now I get your problem.
I think I found a suitable solution in another post:

[UrlEncoding issue for string with ß character](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10405671/urlencoding-issue-for-string-with-%C3%9F-character)

Which in your case could be:

```
var source = "tØst".ToLowerInvariant();
var encodedUrl = HttpUtility.UrlEncode(source, Encoding.GetEncoding(1252));
```

I had to make the string lowercase to better match your current mapping.

Comment: Becuse they do not work. They produce "%c3%b8st" out of "tøst" which is NOT windows-1252 and is interpretted like ""tÃ¸st" and not "tøst".

Comment: I've amended my answer to be more coherent with your question :-)