# What charset encoding is used for HTTP GET requests URL?

Tags: http, encoding, character-encoding, get, request

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What's the correct encoding of HTTP get request strings?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1549213/whats-the-correct-encoding-of-http-get-request-strings)

One of my clients sent me they require HTTP requests to be encoded in ISO-8859-2,

so I wonder about what charset is used for HTTP communication, and if this request is somehow technicaly right.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends. A "smart" server will always use percent-escaped UTF-8, but you can't rely on that.

Comment: and doesn't this depend on application running behind HTTP protocol? on which level is this considered?

Comment: @MarekSebera, the phrasing 'A "smart" server' does indeed mean this depends on "application running behind HTTP protocol".

Answer (score 0):

Pure ASCII is all that's allowed in HTTP headers.   But, as far as HTTP is concerned, anything goes in the request body of a POST.  The headers and body are always separated by a blank line.  A set of headers will normally identify the format of the content/body.  Responses work the same way.   However, HTML has some additional rules regarding what *normally* goes in a POST.

EDIT:  Sorry, I missed the word 'GET' in your title.  Might be nice to duplicate that in the body of your question.

At any rate, I believe I am correct in saying ONLY ASCII (ANSI X3.4-1986) is allowed in the headers of any HTTP request, GET or POST.  So no, ISO-8859-2 requests are not strictly valid HTTP.  That said, there's probably a way to escape the desired special characters in the query string if that's what you're really asking for here.

SOURCE:   https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2616