# sending € character to web server via VBA

Tags: vba, msxml

I am using MSXML2.XMLHTTP60 to send text messages via VBA using a web server. I cannot understand why the € symbol is not displayed when receiving a text message. Other special characters, such as ò,à,è etc are displayed after a conversion function I wrote (for example à is encoded as "%E0"). I suppose that web server is expecting charset iso 8859-1 which doe not support € symbol. Therefore how can I solve this problem?

Comment: Can you post the code you are having an issue with?

Answer (score 1):

If your request is a *POST* request then you can specify header for `Content-Type` with encoding e.g. like this:

```
objHTTP.Open "POST", ...
objHTTP.setRequestHeader "Content-Type", "text/html; charset=utf-8"
```

But for *GET* request the URL with possible query string parameters will be encoded as ASCII. Read e.g. [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1549213/whats-the-correct-encoding-of-http-get-request-strings) post.

Comment: Hi dee, you are absolutely right! I changed "GET" to "POST" and added the string you suggested and it worked! :) I was struggling since days to solve this issue and eventually I managed to iron it out! Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

Using UTF-8 as your character encoding should solve such problems. It may also remove the need for your conversion function. I'm not sure how to set the encoding in your web server, but that's usually well documented.

Comment: Thanks Wiebe. Unfortunately I cannot modify the character setting of the web server I call (at least I think I cannot). I wonder if there is a way to bypass the problem using a encoding function or something like that....